# A generator-like unit creates another unit, and both should be started during boot; is that possible?

Tags: startup, dependencies, systemd-unit

Converting some old-style services using a configuration file to `systemd` units, I wrote a generator-like (i.e.: not actually a systemd generator) service that creates (depending on the configuration file) some services and a target requiring those services.
The target should be started during boot (after the generator ran).

The reason why I did *not* use a normal systemd generator unit was the those are rather limited.

When testing in the running system things seem to work, but after a reboot the target is not started. Typically it's enough to start the target manually.

Here's the essential content of my generator unit:

```systemd
[Unit]
Description=instance generator
Wants=nss-user-lookup.target time-sync.target paths.target
After=nss-user-lookup.target time-sync.target paths.target
Before=default.target iotwatch.target
ConditionPathExists=/etc/iotwatch.conf
Conflicts=shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/lib/iotwatch/iotwatch-generator /run/systemd/system
TimeoutStartSec=10
RestartPreventExitStatus=2 3 4 5 7
SuccessExitStatus=7
StartLimitBurst=100
StartLimitInterval=2
RemainAfterExit=true

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target iotwatch.target
```

The target unit looks like this:

```systemd
[Unit]
Description=iotwatch
Wants=paths.target iotwatch@LOC1.service iotwatch@NFS1.service iotwatch@NFS2.service iotwatch@VAR.service
After=paths.target iotwatch@LOC1.service iotwatch@NFS1.service iotwatch@NFS2.service iotwatch@VAR.service
After=nss-lookup.target time-sync.target

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

The lists for `Wants=` and `After=` are dynamically added by the generator unit.

A typical instance unit essentially looks like this:

```systemd
# generated from /etc/iotwatch.conf for VAR (1fa9d6b1)

[Unit]
Description=iotwatch I/O performance monitor instance "VAR"
SourcePath=/etc/iotwatch.conf
PartOf=iotwatch.target
Requires=iotwatch-generator.service
After=iotwatch-generator.service
Wants=nss-user-lookup.target time-sync.target paths.target
After=nss-user-lookup.target time-sync.target paths.target
ConditionPathExists=/dev/v04/var
Conflicts=shutdown.target

[Service]
Type=forking
WorkingDirectory=/run/iotwatch-VAR
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c '[ -d "/run/iotwatch-VAR" ] || mkdir -p "/run/iotwatch-VAR" || exit 3'
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c '[ -h "/run/iotwatch-VAR/iotwatch-VAR" ] || ln -s "/usr/bin/iotwatch" "/run/iotwatch-VAR/iotwatch-VAR" || exit 3'
ExecStartPre=/bin/sh -c '[ -d "/var/log/iotwatch/VAR" -o 1 -eq 0 ] || mkdir "/var/log/iotwatch/VAR" || exit 3'
ExecStart=@/run/iotwatch-VAR/iotwatch-VAR iotwatch-VAR -l /var/log/iotwatch/VAR/iotwatch-VAR.log -m I -p/run/iotwatch-VAR/iotwatch-VAR.pid -d1 ...
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/sleep 0.2
TimeoutStartSec=10
ExecStop=/run/iotwatch-VAR/iotwatch-VAR -l /var/log/iotwatch/VAR/iotwatch-VAR-stop.log -m I -p/run/iotwatch-VAR/iotwatch-VAR.pid -d0
TimeoutStopSec=30
PIDFile=/run/iotwatch-VAR/iotwatch-VAR.pid
Restart=always
RestartSec=10s
RestartPreventExitStatus=1 3

[Install]
WantedBy=iotwatch.target
```

(The unit is a bit complex, because it was converted from an LSB script that also did what the generator does now)

All services are enabled.
The last command executed by the generator unit before exiting is `/usr/bin/systemctl daemon-reload`.

What could be the problem, and is there a (clean) solution for it?

### What happens during Boot

When I boot the system, the generator is started and target `Default`is being reached.

However I see

> systemd[1]: Failed to start Create Volatile Files and Directories

The reason is that one temporary directory being created uses a user provided by LDAP, and at that point the LDAP client (NSS) is not ready yet.
But I could log in and `systemctl start systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service`.
Still my service units won't start.

The status of the services at that point is:

```sh
# systemctl status iotwatch.target
● iotwatch.target - iotwatch I/O performance monitor
   Loaded: loaded (/run/systemd/system/iotwatch.target; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
# systemctl status iotwatch-generator.service
● iotwatch-generator.service - I/O performance monitor instance generator
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/iotwatch-generator.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Fri 2023-11-24 12:06:16 CET; 20min ago
 Main PID: 3075 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
    Tasks: 0 (limit: 512)
   Memory: 0B
   CGroup: /system.slice/iotwatch-generator.service

Nov 24 12:06:15 rksapv04 systemd[1]: Starting I/O performance monitor instance generator...
Nov 24 12:06:16 rksapv04 systemd[1]: Started I/O performance monitor instance generator.
# systemctl status iotwatch@VAR.service
● iotwatch@VAR.service - iotwatch I/O performance monitor instance "VAR"
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/iotwatch.conf; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

When starting the target manually, all instances start.